# Why not transpile TypeScript with npm's `prepare` life cycle script?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner with both JavaScript and TypeScript.

Many TypeScript projects include a [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts) called `build` in their [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json). The script is meant to transpile code into JavaScript by calling [`tsc`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options):

```
{
    "name": "my-typescript-project",
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^5.1.3",
        …
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        …
    }
    …
}
```

Because `build` isn't any of [npm's life cycle scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts), it isn't executed automatically. Instead, it must be executed manually with the command [`npm run-script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-run-script).

Since version 4.0.0, [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands) supports a [life cycle script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts) called `prepare` which it executes at the following times:

> - Runs BEFORE the package is packed, i.e. during `npm publish` and `npm pack`
> - Runs on local `npm install` without any arguments
> - Runs AFTER `prepublish`, but BEFORE `prepublishOnly`
> - NOTE: If a package being installed through git contains a `prepare` script, its `dependencies` and `devDependencies` will be installed, and the prepare script will be run, before the package is packaged and installed.

By switching from the seemingly common `build` to `prepare` for the purpose of transpiling TypeScript into JavaScript, one would no longer have to transpile code manually, and could install TypeScript projects as [git dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#git-urls-as-dependencies) seamlessly. Why don't TypeScript projects use `prepare` to run `tsc`?

A possible reason to use `build` would be to remain compatible with other package managers; [Yarn doesn't support `prepare` anymore](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/2305#issuecomment-753468942) and [pnpm doesn't either](https://pnpm.io/scripts). However, projects must commit to one package manager; switching to another would require converting the lock file, among other things.